# How to add item to top menu on android

Tags: java, android, android-intent, menu

I want to add a a menu item to the top (Where the class title is). I added the item to menu.xml and also for made an Intent to open a new class after clicking but it does not open my whole app anymore. And when I remove `android:onClick:"history"` it starts working again with out the menu function of course.

Have a look at the picture please: http://snag.gy/udxXc.jpg

That 'History' is my button that needs to open a new class.  and this is my code:

xml:

```
<item
        android:id="@+id/history"
        android:showAsAction="always"
        android:title="History"
        android:onClick="history"/>
```

Java:

```
public void history(View view){
    Intent historyIntent = new Intent(this, History.class);
    startActivity(historyIntent);
}
```

Am i doing it correctly? or any better solution?

Comment: You want to add an item to the ActionBar. Have you looked at the documentation? http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html

Answer (score 0):

> I want to add a a menu item to the top (Where the class title is)

That is called [the action bar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html).

> And when I remove android:onClick:"history" it starts working again with out the menu function of course.

I am not aware that `android:onClick` is valid for `<item>` elements.

> Am i doing it correctly?

Not as far as I am aware.

> or any better solution?

[Override `onOptionsItemSelected()` and respond to the item click there](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#ActionEvents).